# Display Zero Value in Json

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersy for producing Json in an application.
The code snippet which produces Json is as follows

```
    @GET    
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("sample")
    public List<test> displaySampleMessage(@PathParam("id") int id) 
    {
        System.out.println(id);
        List<test> sample1 = new ArrayList<>();

        test temp1 =    new test();
        temp1.setName("abc");   
        sample1.add(temp1);

        return sample1;
    }
```

Test is simple java class with the following code

```
package webServiceTester;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class test 
{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public test()
    {

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public test(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }   
}
```

Then when I run this web service I get the following output
[image]

I do not t want to get age = 0 here because I have not set the age property of my object.
What is its solution. I want age to be appeared if I set the value otherwise it should not appear..

Comment: There is no way anyone can know if an int has value 0 because you set it, or because you didn't and it thus has its default value. You'll need something else, like an Integer (which would be null by default) to do that. And please, respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Ok. I made this example just for testing purposes that's why I don't follow the conventions.

Comment: But thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jakson**, [here](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) you can find a 
JSON example with Jersey + Jackson.
So you can use `@JsonSerialize` annotation to exclude null or empty fields.

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

or

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
```

However it's not a good practice to exclude null or empty fields in restful applications because it may lead errors in client side.